# How does a logical & work on two bytes in C#?

Tags: c#

I recently had a test question:

```
byte a,b,c;
a = 190;
b = 4;
c = (byte)(a & b);
```

What is the value of c?

I have never used a logical operand in this manner, what's going on here? Stepping through this, the answer is 4, but why?

Also, where would this come up in the real world? I would argue that using logical operands in this manner, with a cast, is just bad practice, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logical AND operator, when applied to integers performs a bitwise AND operation. The result is 1 in each position in which a 1 appears in both of the operands.

```
  0011
& 0101
------
  0001
```

The decimal value 190 is equivalent to binary 10111110. Decimal 4 is binary 00000100.

Do a logical AND operation on the bits like this:

```
  10111110
& 00000100
----------
  00000100
```

So the result is 4.

> Also, where would this come up in the real world? I would argue that using logical operands in this manner, with a cast, is just bad practice, but I could be wrong.

These operations are useful in several circumstances. The most common is when using Enum values as flags.

```
[Flags]
public enum MyFileOptions
{
    None = 0,
    Read = 1,   // 2^0
    Write = 2,  // 2^1 
    Append = 4, // 2^2
}
```

If an Enum has values that are powers of two, then they can be combined into a single integer variable (with the Logical OR operator).

```
MyFileOptions openReadWrite = MyFileOptions.Read | MyFileOptions.Write;
```

In this variable, both bits are set, so it indicates that both the Read and Write options are selected.

The logical AND operator can be used to test values.

```
bool openForWriting = ((openReadWrite & MyFileOptions.Write) == MyFileOptions.Write);
```

**NOTE**

A lot of people are pointing out that this is actually a bitwise AND not a logical AND. I looked it up in the spec before I posted, and I was suprised to learn that both versions are referred to as "Logical AND" in the spec. This makes sense because it is performing the logical AND operation on each bit. So you are actually correct in the title of the question.

Comment: Thanks the test actually used the phrase "logical AND," which was throwing me off.

Comment: That is interesting, i had always learned & as bitwise and && as logical from my C++ days...

Comment: @James Michael Hare - C# uses the operators differently from C++. Since C# has a boolean type that is distinct from the numeric types, then the operation is chosen based on the types of the operands. In C#, the difference between & and && is that && is the short-circuited version of the operation, while & requires the evaluation of both operands.

Comment: In the spec && is called "Conditional AND", since it is the short-circuited version.

Comment: Yes, i know they differ in C#, I just meant I was used to calling & bitwise AND from my C++ days.

Answer (score 4):

You are doing a bitwise AND in this case, not a logical AND, it is combining the bits of the two values of a & b and giving you a result that has only the bits set that are both set in a & b, in this case, just the 4s place bit.

```
190 =    10111110
& 4 =    00000100
-------------------
= 4      00000100
```

Edit: Interestingly, msdn itself makes the issue of whether to call it logical vs bitwise a bit muddy.  On their description of the logical operators (& && | || etc) they say logical operators (bitwise and bool) but then on the description of & itself it indicates it performs a bitwise AND for integers and a logical AND for bools.  It appears it is still considered a logical operator, but the action between integer types is a bitwise AND.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbf85k1c(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Just a type, not the 4th bit, but the 3rd one.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear, the 4s bit, not the 4th bit is what i meant to say.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bitwise `AND`, meaning the bits on both bytes are compared, and a 1 is returned if both bits are 1.

```
10111110 &
00000100
--------
00000100
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the uses of a logical & on bytes is in networking and is called the [Binary And Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork#Determining_the_network_prefix).  Basically, you logical and bytes by converting them to binary and doing a logical and on every bit.

Answer (score 0):

In binary

4 == 100
190 == 10111110

& is and AND operation on the boolean operators, so it does de Binary and on 4 and 190 in byte format, so 10111110 AND 100 gives you 100, so the result is 4.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bitwise AND, not a logical AND. Logical AND is a test of a condition ie:

```
if(a && b) doSomething();
```

A bitwise AND looks at the binary value of the two variables and combines them. Eg:

```
10101010 &
00001000
---------
00001000
```

Answer (score 0):

This lines up the binary of the two numbers, like this:

```
10111110
00000100
--------
00000100
```

On each column, it checks to see if both numbers are 1. If it is, it will return 1 on the bottom. Otherwise, it will return 0 on the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

> I would argue that using logical operands in this manner, with a cast, is just bad practice, but I could be wrong.

There is no cast.  `&` is defined on integers, and intended to be used this way.  And just so everyone knows, this technically is a logical operator according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d%28v=VS.80%29.aspx), which I find kind of crazy.